# Node Restructure using XSLT

Tags: xslt

My input xml has few nodes without proper grouping..They are just in serial manner.
I need to create a parent node and put those in following structure using XSLT....am trying without any luck. The reverse seems to be easy. Can anybody help with quick XSLT.

Thank you for your time

**INPUT.XML**

```
<root>
 <info>
  <name>papa</name>
  <age>10</age>

   <groupkey>1</groupkey>
   <groupkey>2</groupkey>
   <groupkey>2</groupkey>


   <groupname>n1</groupname>
   <groupname>n2</groupname>
   <groupname>n3</groupname>



 </info>
</root>
```

**Desire Output**

```
<root>
 <info>
  <name>papa</name>
  <age>10</age>

     <groups>

       <group>
          <groupkey>1</groupkey>
          <groupname>n1</groupname>
       </group>

      <group>
          <groupkey>2</groupkey>
          <groupname>n2</groupname>
       </group>

       <group>
          <groupkey>3</groupkey>
          <groupname>n3</groupname>
       </group>



     </groups>

 </info>
</root>
```

## Adding following

Many Thanks Novatchev . I tested it and exactly what I wanted. Its generic also.
One Last question pls. If I have another node called address like following how will I incorporate it. Pls help.
Thanks for your time.

## Input

```
<root>
 <info>
  <name>papa</name>
  <age>10</age>

    <groupkey>1</groupkey>
    <groupkey>2</groupkey>
    <groupkey>3</groupkey>

    <groupname>n1</groupname>
    <groupname>n2</groupname>
    <groupname>n3</groupname>



    <addresskey>1</addresskey>
    <addresskey>2</addresskey>
    <addresskey>3</addresskey>

    <addressname>a1</addressname>
    <addressname>a2</addressname>
    <addressname>a3</addressname>  


 </info>
</root>
```

## Output

```
<root>
 <info>
  <name>papa</name>
  <age>10</age>

     <groups>

       <group>
          <groupkey>1</groupkey>
          <groupname>n1</groupname>
       </group>

      <group>
          <groupkey>2</groupkey>
          <groupname>n2</groupname>
       </group>

       <group>
          <groupkey>3</groupkey>
          <groupname>n3</groupname>
       </group>

     </groups>


      <addresses>

            <address>
               <addresskey>1</addresskey>
               <addressname>a1</addressname>
            </address>

           <address>
               <addresskey>2</addresskey>
               <addressname>a2</addressname>
            </address>

            <address>
               <addresskey>3</addresskey>
               <addressname>a3</addressname>
            </address>

     </addresses>



 </info>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="age">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <groups>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::groupkey" mode="grouping"/>
  </groups>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="groupkey" mode="grouping">
  <group>
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="grouping" select="../groupname[$vPos]"/>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="groupname" mode="grouping">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="groupkey|groupname"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (with corrected 3rd `groupkey`):

```
<root>
 <info>
  <name>papa</name>
  <age>10</age>

   <groupkey>1</groupkey>
   <groupkey>2</groupkey>
   <groupkey>3</groupkey>

   <groupname>n1</groupname>
   <groupname>n2</groupname>
   <groupname>n3</groupname>

 </info>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <info>
      <name>papa</name>
      <age>10</age>
      <groups>
         <group>
            <groupkey>1</groupkey>
            <groupname>n1</groupname>
         </group>
         <group>
            <groupkey>2</groupkey>
            <groupname>n2</groupname>
         </group>
         <group>
            <groupkey>3</groupkey>
            <groupname>n3</groupname>
         </group>
      </groups>
   </info>
</root>
```

**Update**:

In the meantime the OP updated the question by adding the requirement that a second type of data (address information) exists in the XML document and must be grouped similarly.

**Here is the updated solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="age">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <groups>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::groupkey" mode="grouping"/>
  </groups>
  <addresses>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::addresskey" mode="grouping"/>
  </addresses>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="groupkey" mode="grouping">
  <group>
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="grouping" select="../groupname[$vPos]"/>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="addresskey" mode="grouping">
  <address>
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="grouping" select="../addressname[$vPos]"/>
  </address>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="groupname|addressname" mode="grouping">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="groupkey|groupname|addresskey|addressname"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the newly-specified XML document**:

```
<root>
 <info>
  <name>papa</name>
  <age>10</age>

    <groupkey>1</groupkey>
    <groupkey>2</groupkey>
    <groupkey>3</groupkey>

    <groupname>n1</groupname>
    <groupname>n2</groupname>
    <groupname>n3</groupname>



    <addresskey>1</addresskey>
    <addresskey>2</addresskey>
    <addresskey>3</addresskey>

    <addressname>a1</addressname>
    <addressname>a2</addressname>
    <addressname>a3</addressname>


 </info>
</root>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <info>
      <name>papa</name>
      <age>10</age>
      <groups>
         <group>
            <groupkey>1</groupkey>
            <groupname>n1</groupname>
         </group>
         <group>
            <groupkey>2</groupkey>
            <groupname>n2</groupname>
         </group>
         <group>
            <groupkey>3</groupkey>
            <groupname>n3</groupname>
         </group>
      </groups>
      <addresses>
         <address>
            <addresskey>1</addresskey>
            <addressname>a1</addressname>
         </address>
         <address>
            <addresskey>2</addresskey>
            <addressname>a2</addressname>
         </address>
         <address>
            <addresskey>3</addresskey>
            <addressname>a3</addressname>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </info>
</root>
```

Comment: Many Thanks Novatchev . I tested it and exactly what I wanted. One last question pls how to incorporate another attribute in existing xslt like address. I have updated question above.pls help  Thanks for your time